# directX directInput Keyboard throws E_accessdenied

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I am trying to work with DirectInput keyboard, and my code is throwing a weird error.
I can go through the creation, and setting of everything and they all return S_OK, but when I try to run

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = m_pDIKeyboard->GetDeviceState( sizeof(keyBuffer), (LPVOID)&keyBuffer );
```

hr comes back as (hex address) "access code is invalid", and when I do a check for

```
if(FAILED(hr))
```

it comes back as E_ACCESSDENIED
there are no errors (or warnings for that matter) on the keyBuffer, or any part of the line.

any thoughts on this

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`IDirectInputDevice8::GetDeviceState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.getdevicestate.aspx) give the following possible return values:

> **Return Value**
>   If the method succeeds, the return value is DI_OK. If the method fails, the return value can be one of the following error values: DIERR_INPUTLOST, DIERR_INVALIDPARAM, DIERR_NOTACQUIRED, DIERR_NOTINITIALIZED, E_PENDING.

You should check that none of the `DIERR_*` macros overlap with `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

Further, some code I've seen handles `E_ACCESSDENIED` the same way as `DIERR_INPUTLOST`. You might want to try to re-`Acquire` the input and have another go.

Comment: but then wouldn't it show up as one of those HRESULT values, and not "access code is invalid"