# DirectInput console application

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, directinput

I'm working in C++ in Windows and I need to deal with an input device with force feedback. I found out that one solution could be to use DirectInput and so I start looking at that.

**FIRST QUESTION**: any suggestions on other ways for dealing with force feedback devices? (Win32 app, not UWP)

*Coming back to DirectInput*

The reference starting point I have got in my mind is the [DirectInput Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectInput-Samples-8ac6f5e3), in particular the FFconst example where a constant feedback force is applied to the first device axis according to a value grabbed from a simple GUI. In my case what I want to achieve is having a simple console application where I set a constant force according to a value grabbed from the standard input.

The basic steps for using the DirectInput API, according to the samples and the documentation, are:

- ***create direct input device*** calling [*DirectInput8Create*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee416756(v=vs.85));
- ***look for devices*** calling [*EnumDevices*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee417804%28v%3dvs.85%29) filtering devices and limiting scope to the enumeration according to what you are looking for (in my case I'm filtering for looking only in `DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL` devices and limiting the scope to `DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY | DIEDFL_FORCEFEEDBACK`);
- ***set data format*** for the selected device(s) calling [*SetDataFormat*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee417925(v%3dvs.85)) in order to be able to acquire the device;
- ***set the cooperative level*** for the device(s) calling [*SetCooperativeLevel*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee417921(v%3dvs.85)) once again in order to acquire the device;
- ***use the device...***

Now, all goes well until we encounter the *SetCooperativeLevel* mehtod since it needs as input a `HWND` window handle *"to be associate to the device"* and which *"must be a valid top-level window handle that belongs to the process"*. Since I'm writing a console application I need to find a valid `HWND` pointer: I sorted the problem out following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/124103/how-to-obtain-a-console-window-handle-hwnd) suggestion. Anyway, the `HWND` pointer I get in that way seems not to be a valid window handle since I get a `E_HANDLE` error, as I would specify `nullptr` as argument. I found out that specifying the argument through the call of [*GetTopWindow*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633514(v=vs.85).aspx) allows not to get the invalid handle error. However I'm not able to acquire the device and I get the `DIERR_OTHERAPPHASPRIO` error, which is nothing more than `E_ACCESSDENIED`. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9425620/9870552) that it seems someone use to treat that error in the same way the `DIERR_INPUTLOST` error is treated, i.e. re-acquiring the device in a while loop as shown in the [*Joystick* direct input sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectInput-Samples-8ac6f5e3/sourcecode?fileId=121930&pathId=1414531679) in the *UpdateInputState* function. Anyway trying this I'm not able to exit that loop, i.e. the device device keep being denied.

That said I end up with the

**SECOND QUESTION**: how to use the DirectInput API in a console application or inside a DLL? (Win32) In case of a console application I'd like to understand why the steps I've done don't work, and in case of a DLL I'd like to know if anyone has an idea on which `HWND` pointer could be used.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081334/using-createwindowex-to-make-a-message-only-window

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a function to get a console application's window for uses like this.

```
HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindow(void);
```